# How can I get similar print result of NSLog for int enum in swift?

Tags: swift, nslog

```
enum ImportType: Int {
    case First = 1
    case None
    case Original
}

var type: ImportType = .First

print(type)                     --------------------> This will output "First"

NSLog("%@", String(type)        --------------------> I can't do this.

NSLog("%d", type.rawValue)      --------------------> This will output "1"
```

Hi All,

I want to get similar result of NSLog as the print function, it more readable for people, but I can't found a way to do this, I got some result that need to do additional handling inside the enum, but I am using other body's source code and just want to collect some information directly.

Are there easy transform way to do what I want?

Thanks~~

Eric

Comment: Do you want `1` as the output? How about `print(type.rawValue)`?

Comment: I want "First" as the result

Comment: Well, as you said, just `print(type)`. What's the problem?

Comment: I want to got the result from NSLog, not print, because I need to dump log to console.

Comment: Oh, right. You want to get the result _using_ NSLog, not "_of_" as in your title. Is that right? Why though? `NSLog` is not Swifty.

Comment: I am not sure, but all my code are written by swift, I used print before, but I need dump to console this time, so I try to use NSLog to dump the debug message.

Comment: @彭煥閎 `NSLog("%@", String(describing: type))` or `"\(type)"`

Comment: Thank Leo, that what I want !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` uses `String.init(describing:)` under the hood to convert whatever you give it to a `String`, so you can do that too:

```
NSLog("%@", String(describing: type))
```

But really though, the enum should conform to `CustomStringConvertible`:

```
enum ImportType: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    
    case First = 1
    case None
    case Original
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .First:
            return "First"
        case .None:
            return "None"
        case .Original:
            return "Original"
        }
    }
}
```

and you should not rely on this default behaviour of `String(describing:)`, because its behaviour is not specified unless the type conforms to `TextOutputStreamable`, `CustomStringConvertible` or `CustomDebugStringConvertible`. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2427941-init) for more info.